# Find differences between two strings with regex

Tags: regex

I have been provided with two example input strings:

"Russia has entered the WWII in [A] [B] after german invasion"

"Russia has entered the WWII in September 1941 after german invasion"

There can be any characters before, after and between the [A] and [B] in the first string and there could be additional placeholders e.g. [C] [D] etc. Each placeholder can only occur once.

How can I use regex to match "September" and "1941"?

I need to match each placeholder in a single regex, not multiple steps.

**My thoughts at a solution**

I'm guessing the solution will be something like:

'Match everything in string 2 after everything before [A] in string 1 and before everything after [A] in string 1'.

I figured out `(.*(:?\[A\]))` and `((:?\[A\]).*)` to get the text before and after the [A] in the first string, but can't figure out how to use that to look at the second string. Perhaps I need to concatenate the two things with some sort of delimiter and look at either side of the delimiter?

Comment: You may split with `(?:\s*\[[^\]]*])+`

Comment: Replace placeholders with `\S+` and add `^` and `$` anchors at the beginning and ending of regex respectfully.

Comment: @revo thanks, but I don't follow. Please can you give an example?

Comment: [Please check this](https://www.regex101.com/r/u7fQjr/1).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like match the fragments around `[A]` and `[B]` to search in the second term for their respective values. You can do this in two steps. First, you need to extract the terms around the `[A]` and `[B]`. This can be done with the following regular expression: `^(.*?)(\[A\])(.*?)(\[B\])(.*?)$`. In a second step, you need to create a new regular expression out of the result of the first one. The three matched groups (the values in the round brackets form a group) would then be the fragments around the terms `[A]` and `[B]`. You then need to create a new regular expression out of those three fragments. Here, the implementation differs for every programming language. In JavaScript, the matching object can be used to create a new regular expression like this: `new RegExp(matches1[1] + '(.*?)' + matches1[2] + '(.*?)' + matches1[3])`. Finally, you end up with the match of the two values.

**Here, the example is implemented in JavaScript:**

```js
var text1 = "Russia has entered the WWII in [A] [B] after german invasion";
var regex1 = new RegExp(/^(.*?)\[A\](.*?)\[B\](.*?)$/);
var matches1 = text1.match(regex1);

var text2 = "Russia has entered the WWII in September 1941 after german invasion";
var regex2 = new RegExp(matches1[1] + '(.*?)' + matches1[2] + '(.*?)' + matches1[3]);
var matches2 = text2.match(regex2);

console.log(matches2[1]);
console.log(matches2[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to match each placeholder in a single regex, not multiple steps. I suspect the correct answer is "This is not possible with Regex".